# Golang Ctx WIthTimeOut in Clojure

Tags: go, clojure

In clojure concurrency, I would like the thread that I spawn kill itself if it take to long to do it's task, similar to what Golang ctx withtimeout provide. how should i do it?

Mind you I dont have any knowledge of java thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can't kill a Java thread cleanly, so people usually write very long-running threads to check a flag occasionally, and keep working only if appropriate.

On the other hand, a thread's client can stop waiting for an answer.  If you start the thread with `future`, you can use the timeout parameter on `deref` at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/deref, or check on it with `future-done?`.

When you have a lot of async stuff going on, the better Go-like algebra in Clojure's core.async library can be helpful (https://clojure.github.io/core.async/) as an alternative to raw Java threads.

Comment: this is really helpful thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

never mind, apparently there is something called future and promise..